# Does not capture events after cloning - jquery bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the code below to clone the accordion. But when trying to expand, the accordion that was cloned the captured event fires the parent accordion. I know the clone event is limited, but how to solve this problem?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-add-panel">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Nova Observação
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
                                Collapsible Group Item #1
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var $template = $(".panel-default");

    var hash = 1;
    $(".btn-add-panel").on("click", function () {
        hash++
        var $newPanel = $template.clone(true).insertAfter($template);
        $newPanel.find(".panel-heading").attr("id", "heading-" + hash);
        $newPanel.find("a").attr("href", "#collapse-" + hash).attr("aria-controls", "collapse-" + hash).attr("class", "collapsed").attr("aria-expanded", "false").attr("data-parent","#collapse-" + hash);
        $newPanel.find(".panel-collapse").attr("id", "collapse-" + hash).attr("aria-labelledby", "heading-" + hash).attr("aria-expanded", "false").removeClass("in");
        $("#accordion").append($newPanel.fadeIn());
        $("#collapse-" + hash).css({ 'height:': '0px'})
    });
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kzpfm1hs/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of the issue is setting [jQuery clone's](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) `withDataAndEvents` to `true`. This should not be necessary as [it looks like](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/js/collapse.js#L200) Bootstrap is using event delegation for handling the accordion/collapse functionality (as opposed to binding event handling directly to the element). So I don't think you need to copy over any events or data from the `$template` element.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/r6L2ag53/1/) is an alternative forked version of your original JSFiddle.

First I removed the `true` argument to the `clone` call (i.e., from `$template.clone(true)` to just `$template.clone()`).

Next I removed the `insertAfter($template)` call since it looks like you are already appending the cloned element to the DOM with `$("#accordion").append($newPanel.fadeIn());`.

Lastly, I changed the following line from:

```
$newPanel.find("a").attr("href", "#collapse-" + hash).attr("aria-controls", "collapse-" + hash).attr("class", "collapsed").attr("aria-expanded", "false").attr("data-parent", "#collapse-" + hash);
```

To:

```
$newPanel.find("a").attr("href", "#collapse-" + hash).attr("aria-controls", "collapse-" + hash).attr("class", "collapsed").attr("aria-expanded", "false").attr("data-target", "#collapse-" + hash);
```

Since I figured you were trying to change the collapse toggle target, instead of the accordion parent element (i.e., from `attr("data-parent", "#collapse-" + hash)` to `attr("data-target", "#collapse-" + hash)`).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Looks like this addresses the actual problem.  Glad this was picked up and taken further than my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a working solution for you, but it is admittedly a bit of a hack to work around the problem.

It appears that as long as the first accordion is never collapsed, all accordions cloned from it will work.  As soon as that first accordion is collapsed even once, all additional clones are "broken" in that they trigger the collapse of that first accordion.

So, if you immediately clone and hide the first accordion, the first clone will serve as your initial visible accordion, and all future clones will work.

https://jsfiddle.net/kzpfm1hs/9/

```js
var $template = $(".panel-default");
var hash = 1;

$(".btn-add-panel").on("click", function() {
  cloneAccordion();
});

function cloneAccordion() {
  hash++;
  var $newPanel = $template.clone(true).insertAfter($template);
  $newPanel.find(".panel-heading").attr("id", "heading-" + hash);

  //Aqui foi feito modificações, adicionado o ultimo método
  $newPanel.find("a").attr("href", "#collapse-" + hash).attr("aria-controls", "collapse-" + hash).attr("class", "collapsed").attr("aria-expanded", "false").attr("data-parent", "#collapse-" + hash);

  $newPanel.find(".panel-collapse").attr("id", "collapse-" + hash).attr("aria-labelledby", "heading-" + hash).attr("aria-expanded", "false").removeClass("in");
  $("#accordion").append($newPanel.fadeIn());
  $("#collapse-" + hash).css({
    'height:': '0px'
  })
}
cloneAccordion();
$template.hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-add-panel">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Novo
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-1">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse-1">
                                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                                </a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse-1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-1">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
              raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Grateful, there are hours without solution to the problem. thank you.

Comment: Glad to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Let me know if you have any related questions.